# How to timeout a sentence?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to write script in groovy that does a some http requests and measure the time of it. Unfortunately, there are some requests that may be too slow to wait for it. I need to check if they are running for some part of time (eg. 1 minute) and if they didn't stop, I need to force stop of executing it.

```
start = new Date()
value = select.toURL().text // this needs to be timeouted after 1 minute
stop = new Date()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

```
import java.util.Timer;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Then you can schedule a task like:

```
  // creating timer task, timer
  TimerTask tasknew = new TimerSchedulePeriod();
  Timer timer = new Timer();

  // scheduling the task at interval
  timer.schedule(tasknew,100, 100);
```

Or if you are lazy something like:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
    public void run() {
    // Your code here
    }
  }, timeInMilli);
```